# Change datetime to date in MVC 3 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the MVC 3 with C#  and I have a problem when displaying dates in a dropdown list.
Dates are displayed as follow: **4/21/2011 12:00:00** AM, but I just want to format them this way:  **4/21/2011**, which is exactly the format in my database.

The date attribute in the database is date and not datetime.

The code in the model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{mm/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=false)]
public DateTime? booksDate { get; set; }
```

the controller looks like this:

```
 var booksDates = from dates in db.Books
                             orderby dates.booksDate
                             select new { dates.booksDate};

          ViewBag.Dates = BooksDates.Distinct();
```

and finally the code in my view:

```
<td>Books dates</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownList("booksDate", new SelectList(ViewBag.Dates as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "booksDate", "booksDate"), "Select a date") </td>
```

Where i'm wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Where does `livreDate` come in? I can't see it mentioned anywhere apart from your model...

Comment: Hi jon, you're right, livreDate is mentioned anywhere, it was just a bad copy paste, but in my real code its booksDate not livreDate

Answer (score 5):

You could try to put to use a regular html dropdown and set the html values by hand. I'm sure there's a better way and it might be dirty, but it gets the job done.

Controller:

```
ViewBag.Dates = BooksDates.Distinct();
```

View:

```
<select>
@foreach (var date in ViewBag.Dates)
{
    <option>
       @Convert.ToDateTime(date.StartDate).ToShortDateString()
    </option>

}
</select>
```

Comment: i have used this example, for `dd/MM/yyyy` format [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29611490/2218697), thank's to all

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not completely off the `DataFormatString` should look like this:

```
DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
```

or even simpler using short date format:

```
DataFormatString="{0:d}"
```

Comment: I already tried this, but i always have this format: 4/21/2011 12:00:00 AM while i want this format: 4/21/2011

Answer (score 0):

You could extend helper class to do the job in view.

```
public static class FormatHelper
{
    public static IHtmlString ToDate( this HtmlHelper helper, DateTime datetime )
    {
        return new HtmlString( datetime.ToShortDateString() );
    }
}
```

In view:

```
@Html.ToDate( Model.Date )
```

Dont forget to import namespace to view.

Answer (score 0):

As like as 
 in controller:

```
ViewBag.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedDate);
```

in view

```
@Convert.ToDateTime(ViewData["Date"].ToString()).ToShortDateString()
```

output like:

> 03/02/2017

Answer (score -1):

You can do it on pure c# by doing:

```
string date = Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: Hi Eric, i know i can do this in pure c# but where and how exactly ? because i have to do it in my model, controler, or the view (dropdownlist). In other words, i have to respect the MVC architecture

Answer (score -1):

if you are using sql, you can do it this way:

```
select field1, convert(nvarchar(10), field2, 101)
```

from table
where //whatever,

let me explain what is all this about:

-field2 is the date containing field.
-nvarchar(10) is the type that you will revieve. This hasn't much importance, because it's the type of that you're reciveing ( the result of the convertion). Like it's a select, you don't care about the data type here. It's only for showing the data. The number 10 is the lenght of the string you're getting.

-field2 :

the field that you want to convert ( the date with the hour)

101: it's the style.
This tells the field2 that has to print only the month/day/year.

There's a lot of styles, you should google them!

I hope it works.