# DisplayTemplate for object in the ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to display a date stored in the ViewBag and i need to use DisplayTemplate for this. Now if it was a date in the model i would use DisplayFor helper, but how can i do it for the ViewBag?

What i have is the following:

**Views\Shared\DateTime.cshtml**

```
@model DateTime
@Html.Display("",Model.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@((DateTime)ViewBag.Date)
```

**Controller**

```
ViewBag.Date = DateTime.Now
```

What should i change in the view in order to have ViewBag.Date display in "dd-MMM-yyyy format?

I know i can do it by:

```
@(((DateTime)ViewBag.Date).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

But in this case, i have to do this for each time i want to display a date from ViewBag, and what if i want to change the format? I will have to make many changes.

Comment: Is there any reason why it HAS to be a DisplayTemplate?

Comment: Why isn't it in the view model?

Comment: Well, i want the date to be formatted in a specific way. For instance in my DisplayTemplate i define Dates to be displayed in dd-MM-yyyy format. I want this to happen for the value in the ViewBag.

Answer (score 4):

to change date format for each item

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Balance)
{
@Convert.ToDateTime(item.StartDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
}
```

to explore more check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5907040/2218697), explains `ToShortDateString()`, hope helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

there's no overload of Display which takes a value as argument.

So.

You can simply do

```
@ViewBag.disp
```

or (if it contains HTMl)

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.disp)
```

or if you want a TextBox

```
@Html.TextBox("disp", (string)@ViewBag.disp, new{@readonly = true})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This looks promising. Let me let you know when i check it out.

Comment: Though this works as in it displays data, it doesn't use the DisplayTemplate specified for DateTime. I need to use DisplayTemplate. I know i could just do @(((DateTime)ViewBag.Date).ToString(formatString)) .

Comment: Well buddy if you display it in the date format then you have the solution. just do it..

Comment: Just Simple! Fill your ViewBag in whichever format you want for your date and display it like a string in client side `ViewBag.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");`

Comment: Thanks, but i do know how to do this. My problem is how to use the DisplayTemplate, instead of defining the format.

Answer (score 0):

There is no overload of Display with parameter value.
Although there is a workaround that works just fine with any value.
Create in your sollution a partial with a name for example _Value.cshtml
the content of the partial is:

@{

```
Layout = null;
```

}

@Html.DisplayForModel()

then in your page simply call the partial like this:

@Html.Partial("_Value", myValue)

and myValue will be rendered using the defined DisplayTemplate for this type of value (DateTime, bool or whatever type you want)